# Is it helpful to create a multi-column index if the columns are already indexed on their own?

Tags: sql, database, indexing, sqlite

Let's say your table has three columns:

1. time (integer)
2. name (varchar)
3. other_column (varchar)

and you have two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX index_time ON my_table (time);
CREATE INDEX index_name ON my_table (name);
```

In this case, does it make any difference if I create a new index based on both time and name? i.e.:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name_and_time ON my_table (name,time);
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards overall performance the three indexes may be overkill and have a detrimental affect when inserting as there are then the three indexes to maintain and the extra memory/space utilisation.

However, the first factor would be to ascertain if the indexes would actually be utilised which depends upon what queries are to be run.

From a brief play with the following code, which you could use as the basis to explore more fully  (`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN your_query` being a tool to use):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_time;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_name;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_name_and_time;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (time INTEGER, name TEXT, other TEXT);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_time ON my_table (time); -- INDEX 1
-- CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_name ON my_table (name); -- INDEX 2
-- CREATE INDEX index_name_and_time ON my_table (name,time); -- INDEX 3

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM my_table; -- QUERY 1

-- EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
-- SELECT time, name, other FROM my_table -- QUERY 2

-- EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
-- SELECT time, name, other FROM my_table ORDER BY time, name; -- QUERY 3 

-- EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
-- SELECT time, name, other FROM my_table ORDER BY name, time; -- QUERY 4
```

The following results can be obtained :-

#### First two Queries, no advantage, just disadvantage.

Having no indexes through to having all 3 makes no difference to the first 2 queries (basically the same). **None use any of the indexes when 0,1,2 or 3 indexes are available.** They use **SCAN TABLE my_table**

#### The 3rd Query

- Without any indexes then **SCAN TABLE my_table** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY**
- With just the first index **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_time** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY**.
- With the 1st and 2nd **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_time** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY**.
- With just the 2nd **SCAN TABLE my_table** and  **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY**
- With all 3 **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_time** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY**
- With just the 3rd **SCAN TABLE my_table** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY**

#### The 4th query

- Without any **SCAN TABLE my_table** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY**
- With 1 **SCAN TABLE my_table** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY**
- With 1 and 2 **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_name** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY**
- With 2 **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_name** and **USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY**
- With 1,2 and 3 **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_name_and_time**
- With just 3 **SCAN TABLE my_table USING INDEX index_name_and_time**

Of course this is not factoring in timings as the tables are empty. The code above could easily be adapted to include data and thus then have timings applied. Note you also perhaps ant to consider effects other than running queries, such as insertions and deletions which would alter the indexes.

---

### The Answer - It depends.

So at least from a index utilisation point of view it's quite clear that an index being useful or not is dependant upon the queries used.

Answer (score 0):

The third index, `(name, time)` is redundant with `(name)`.

You should probably drop the `(name)` index and just include `(name, time)` and `(time)` -- if those are the indexes that you think you need.